# Infer the type value of a "resolved" generic on child classes

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic http response factory based on the return type of use-cases, the return type of a use-case is always a generic called `Result`, that has the following structure:

```
export type Result<E, S> = Failure<E, S> | Success<E, S>;

export class Failure<E, S> {
    constructor(private _value: E) {
    }

    isError(): this is Failure<E, S> {
        return true;
    }

    value(): E {
        return this._value
    }

    isSuccess(): this is Success<E, S> {
        return false;
    }
}

export class Success<E, S> {

    constructor(private _value: S) {
    }

    value(): S {
        return this._value;
    }

    isError(): this is Failure<E, S> {
        return true;
    }

    isSuccess(): this is Success<E, S> {
        return true;
    }
}
```

example usage on a use-case:

```
type CreateUserResult = Result<UserAlreadyExistsError | UnexpectedError, User>

export class CreateUserUseCase {
  execute(params: any): CreateUserResult
}
```

types of the possible returns:

```
class UserAlreadyExistsError extends Error {}
class UnexpectedError extends Error {}
class User {
   constructor(private name: string)
}
```

on the controller, I inject the accordingly HTTP response factory to format the result (either success or failure) to the correct HTTP code, status, message, etc.

example:

```
class CreateUserController {
    create(request: HttpRequest): HttpResponse {
        const createUserResult = new CreateUserUseCase({})
        return this.createUserHttpResponseFactory.make(createUserResult);
    }
}
```

http response factory structure:

```
abstract class HttpResponseFactory<T> {
    
    public make(result: T): HttpResponse {
        if (result.isError()) return this.parseError(result.value());
        return this.parseSucess(result.value());
    }

    protected parseError(result: typeof Failure): HttpResponse {
        return response.status(HttpCode.InternalServerError).json({})
    }

    protected abstract parseSucess(result: typeof Success): HttpResponse;
}
```

I want the child classes of the `HttpResponseFactory` to be able to infer the `Failure` or the `Success` type of the Result, I've tried to use `typeof Sucess | typeof Failure` as the type of the `make(result): HttpResponse` method but got no success, even the parent abstract class is not able to infer the type and check the `isError()` method

this is an example of the desired result:

```
class createUserHttpResponseFactory extends HttpResponseFactory<CreateUserResult> {

    protected parseSucess(response: UserAlreadyExistsError | UnexpectedError): HttpResponse {
    }

    protected parseSucess(response: User): HttpResponse {
    }
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: What is `UserAlreadyExistsError`? What is `UnexpectedError`? What is `User`?  Et cetra.  Please provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone error where others can quickly get to work solving the problem instead of spending time or effort re-creating it.

Comment: I would suggest abandoning type predicates and instead just using a discriminated union like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgZM0W) shows.  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, please tell me what I'm missing (preferably with a [mre])

Comment: as for the first question, I just trimmed out irrelevant parts. those errors are just for the example, it's basically error classes that extend from the base `Error` class, the `User` class in this example is the "successful" result of the use-case, it could be anything.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, could you do an example of how this would be implemented to the HttpResponseFactory?

Comment: I don't know, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEPXVW) maybe?  It's hard for me to know since you haven't defined the types like I've asked you to.  If you paste your own code into a standalone IDE it should only have the problems you care about, and not other problems that serve to distract from the issue.

Comment: this solution didn't work, i'm going to update the question with the types.

Comment: Your updated types don't change anything about my solution, so I need more information here.  What, *specifically*, doesn't work about it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make your abstract class a bit more generic and add a base Entity to extend from, something like

```
//New base entity to be used in the abstract class
class Entity {
  constructor(private name: string) {}
}
class User extends Entity {
  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
}


abstract class HttpResponseFactory<T extends Result<Error, Entity>> {
  public make(result: T) {
    if (result.isError()) return this.parseError(result.value());
    return this.parseSucess(result.value());
  }

  //Expects something that extends Error
  protected parseError<E extends Error>(result: E) {
    //return response.status(HttpCode.InternalServerError).json({});
  }

  //Expect something that extends the base entity as success
  protected abstract parseSucess<S extends Entity>(result: S): any;
}
```

Then on the implementation you can define types that will match you the abstract class, like

```
class CreateUserHttpResponseFactory extends HttpResponseFactory<CreateUserResult> {
  protected parseError(result: UserAlreadyExistsError | UnexpectedError): any {}

  protected parseSucess(result: User): any {}
}
```

I hope it shines a light xD